# Polynomial factoring issue

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I am dealing with an issue for which I do not find answer on the Internet.
When I factorize a polynomial, I can get this structure:

$$
(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)^2
$$

But sometimes I have seen others like:
$$
k(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)^2
$$

Where $k$ is any real number. What does it mean? I know it is related with the coefficient of the root with the highest algebraic multiplicity but I don't get to understand it.

It could be $\frac{1}{3}(x-1)(x-2)$ but never $(x-1)(x-2)+\frac{1}{3}$ isn't it? Why? Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$k$ is the leading coefficient, the coefficient of the highest power of the variable.  That is, if you expand out $k (x - a)(x-b)(x-c)^2$ you'll get $k x^4 + $ (terms in lower powers of $x$).  It has nothing to do with the roots.

On the other hand, $(x-1)(x-2)+\frac{1}{3}$ is not a factorization.  To factorize something means to write it as a product of things, not as a product plus something else.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Simple and complete!